# Вшить иконку в приложение C#

Tags: c#, winforms, icon

Есть приложение, написал на C#. Реализовано через формочки.
Нужно, что бы иконка, которую я нарисовал, была "вшита" в приложение и отображалась не только в "строке названия", но и на рабочем столе. И что бы это оставалось так и не только на моем компе.

Если добавлять иконку через "properties", то она будет видна только в "строке названия"

[image: img1]

А, непосредственно, на рабочем столе или в папке останется стандартный значок:

[image: img2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Project Properties (Alt + F7) - там все указывается и настраивается на первой же вкладке. Icon and Manifest. А вы всего лишь в своем первом примере указали, какую иконку использовать конкретной форме, а не проекту (аппликации) в целом. 
Скомпилировав проект и получив exe-файл (я подразумеваю, что вся функциональность у Вас в проекте "выходит" в один файл без dll и прочих ресурс файлов - простите за банальное описание), то иконка аппликации будет, как Вы выразились, "вшита" и exe-файл, и, будучи перенесенным на другие компьютеры (простите опять за банальность объяснения), будет отображаться именно с "вшитой" иконкой.

Comment: спасибо! помогло

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.